# Get time taken for test running in TeamCity

Tags: node.js, teamcity

I am doing request on `http://[server name]/app/rest/builds/id:[build id]/statistics`, and get response like:

```
<properties count="36">
    <property name="ArtifactsSize" value="1274836"/>
    <property name="BuildArtifactsPublishingTime" value="97"/>
    <property name="BuildCheckoutTime" value="1480093"/>
    <property name="BuildDuration" value="7324057"/>
    <property name="BuildDurationNetTime" value="5843867"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:artifactsPublishing" value="107"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:buildFinishing" value="3"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_107" value="20868"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_11" value="107"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_13" value="334"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_14" value="3671"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:firstStepPreparation" value="113"/>
    <property name="buildStageDuration:sourcesUpdate" value="1480310"/>
    <property name="BuildTestStatus" value="1"/>
    <property name="InspectionStatsE" value="0.000000"/>
    <property name="InspectionStatsW" value="0.000000"/>
    <property name="PassedTestCount" value="24"/>
    <property name="SampleStatistics" value="1"/>
    <property name="SuccessRate" value="1"/>
    <property name="TimeSpentInQueue" value="154"/>
    <property name="TotalTestCount" value="24"/>
    <property name="VisibleArtifactsSize" value="1266844"/>
</properties>
```

How to get the time taken for running the test?

Comment: what node module are you using for this?

Comment: Does it matter? 
Now, I am doing this just from browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about running test in build using the following REST API request:

```
http://teamcity/app/rest/testOccurrences?locator=build:(id:<buildID>)
```

More details here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-Tests.

Comment: I am doing this request: `<teamcity-server>/guestAuth/app/rest/testOccurrences?locator=build:(id:111)`, and getting: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`